# Why is my widget not taking up all the space in the bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: android, flutter, frontend

I'm new to Flutter and I just start coding the UI of a chat app so I figure out that my widget doesn't take all the space of the bottom navigation bar like the photo shows : [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcTDA.png)

This is my camera widget code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraState createState() => _CameraState();
}

class _CameraState extends State<Camera> {
  File _image;

  final imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final image = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 80.0,
              height: 80.0,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: getImage,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.camera_alt_rounded,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue[600],
                  size: 35.0,
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.lightBlue[50],
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[100], spreadRadius: 3),
          ],
        ),
        height: 50,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the chat screen code :

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:mychat/services/auth.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mychat/chat/chat.dart';
import 'package:mychat/widgets/Med_form.dart';
import 'package:mychat/widgets/bottomButtons.dart';
import 'package:mychat/widgets/camera.dart';
import 'package:mychat/widgets/incrementAndDecrement.dart';
import 'package:mychat/widgets/yesOrno.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  File _image;

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  List<String> messages = [
    'fizikefgzerpgr',
    'fioezhfejzifojef',
    'fvfzerfergnyolnkyokjy',
    'rgop^l^lmf^prlgprgprp'
  ];
  List<String> responses = [
    'fizikefgzerpgr',
    'fezfzefzefezff',
    'ofpkoepzkfopkzef',
    'fjeziofjiozejfozejf'
  ];

  //final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(90),
          child: AppBar(
            title: new Text(
              "لاباس ⸮",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topRight,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      colors: [Colors.blueGrey[300], Colors.grey[50]])),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await _auth.signOut();
                  })
            ],
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
        ),
        body: Chat_page(messages: messages, responses: responses),
        bottomNavigationBar: Camera(),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

and this is the code of the messages:

```
import 'package:bubble/bubble.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Chat_page extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> messages;
  List<String> responses;

  Chat_page({this.messages, this.responses});

  @override
  _Chat_pageState createState() => _Chat_pageState();
}

class _Chat_pageState extends State<Chat_page> {
  String message;
  int data;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        /* Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 10),
          child: Text(
            "Today, 10",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ), */
        Flexible(
          child: widget.messages.length > 0
              ? ListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: widget.messages.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
                        children: [
                          widget.messages.length > 0
                              ? chat(widget.messages[index].toString(), 1)
                              : Container(),
                          widget.responses.length > 0
                              ? chat(widget.responses[index].toString(), 0)
                              : Container(),
                        ],
                      ))
              : Container(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}

Widget chat(String message, int data) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment:
          data == 1 ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        data == 0
            ? Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Bubble(
              radius: Radius.circular(15.0),
              color: data == 0 ? Color(0xFFf7ede2) : Color(0xFFf7ede2),
              elevation: 0.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
                      child: Text(
                        message,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ),
        data == 1
            ? Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

so how can I fix this the make my camera widget take the full space

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: Container(
```

to

```
Container(
     height: 100,
     width:double.infinty,
```